# Creating a lookup formula with 2 criteria -- matching IDs and a date in a specific range

Tags: excel, google-sheets, spreadsheet, vlookup, array-formulas

could anyone give me any guidance on this sample workbook?

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1eRa43WPueJBeS7D-Y1GpcrqlWjiKCTm2yZbrfErdI6A/edit#gid=1074678731

What I'm trying to do is the following...

In the MAIN tab, I want to add a formula to the "Cost" (Column D) that populates data from the "Cost" in the COST_ENTRY tab -- depending on whether or not the channel name matches, and whether or not the date falls within a certain range.

I came up with the following formula that seems to work, however it needs to be manually dragged down.

```
=INDEX(COST_ENTRY!D$2:D,MATCH(1,IF(A2>=COST_ENTRY!A2:A,IF(A2<=COST_ENTRY!B$2:B,IF(B2=COST_ENTRY!C$2:C,1))),0))
```

I believe I need an ARRAYFORMULA so it will autopopulate whenever the workbook refreshes with new data. And I understand that INDEX functions do not work in arrays, so I'm stumped.

I had one suggestion, but it would involve pivoting the cost entry form, and that's not really feasible -- since the number of channels would exceed 4.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Which do you want, Excel or Google Sheets, they are similar but things like this will be accomplished in different ways that will not cross platforms.

Comment: What's wrong with having to "manually drag" the formula down?  If you prefer, you could copy-and-paste it.  ...Just copy it as far down as your data might eventually go, and if your concerned about errors showing, then wrap the formula in `IFERR` to prevent the errors, like `=IFERR( Your Formula Here ,"")`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you already have partial solution (in Column H) - as I understand, you see the problem in manualy pivoting the data. Simple solution, based on code you already have, is to pivot data automatically based on "COST_ENTRY" sheet. On sample workbook you provided I added another sheet - "COST_ENTRY_PIVOT" and in F1 altered code from H1.

Code that automatically pivot your data is:

```
=QUERY({COST_ENTRY!A:D},"select Col1, sum(Col4) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 pivot Col3")
```

and final formula for getting Cost is (based on code you already had):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({"Matts Help + Pivot";IF(A2:A="",,VLOOKUP(A2:A,COST_ENTRY_PIVOT!A2:Z,MATCH(B2:B,COST_ENTRY_PIVOT!A1:1,0),TRUE))})
```

I added new "Channel 5" and new date in "COST_ENTRY" sheet and it works.